# Transfer data between two ViewModels

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have two Views and two ViewModels in my WPF app. I am using MVVM `ViewModelLocator` to transfer data to and fro between my ViewModels. Is this the recommended practice? Is there a better way to achieve this? I am currently using this code to access properties of ViewModel2 in ViewModel1

```
var _viewmodel2 = (Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator).ViewModel2;
```

Thanks

Comment: You could also inject a singlton, ISharedData, into each vm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is something like the Event Aggregator pattern. It will use a central 'aggregator' object and subscribing/raising events (with payloads) to ferry data back and forth. Yes, a bit complicated. If your scenario is complex enough for this , here is some more information from a previous SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081077/is-eventaggregator-only-for-viewmodels-in-mvvm)

However......If your scenario is less complicated, you are ok maintaining a reference in viewmodel A to viewmodel B and vice versa. Which seems like it is what you are doing with the ViewModelLocator (which actually uses DI behind the scenes to resolve the instance of ViewModel you are after). This does not violate the MVVM pattern. You just want to be sure to clean up after yourself if during the course of your data share you are subscribing to any events across the viewmodels (same case with event aggregator solution).

Comment: I am using MVVMLight Messenger now to transfer strings from one ViewModel to another. My setup is not complicated so I guess no need for Event Aggregator. What are your views on using Messenger to achieve this goal?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with MVVMLight Messenger so had to look it up. So the Event Aggregator is a pattern and this MVVMLight Messenger looks like an implementation of that pattern :) But in my experience it comes with significant overhead, and performance hit, but it may just be the implementation I am using (internal toolkit). Are you experiencing this with MVVMLight messenger?

Comment: Yes it has overhead but not so much of performance hit. However I think that if Laurent Bugnion has used Event Aggregator to create MVVMLight Messenger service for MVVMLight Toolkit then it would be better to use that as this implementation will always comply with MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you register your viewmodels in a service locator or IoC container, you can simply fetch the reference from there.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyViewModel>()
```

Above example uses MvvmLight

Comment: Yes that is what I am currently using in the original question, I am asking that is there a bad side effect of using this method. Is there a better way. By bad side effect I mean performance issues by creating instants and when the app gets bigger and bigger, the to and fro references will increase